# How to have accurate collisions in Flash CS6 (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i am creating an endless runner game and the player as to jump over an obstacle, and if he touches it he looses health. The current collision code is this:

```
 if (man_mc.hitTestObject(crate_mc)) {
    health--;
    health_txt.text=health.toString();
```

which is inside a loop. But the problem is that my obstacles are triangles, so when you jump over them if you touch the 'hit box' or dimensions of the triangle you loose health. So how do i make it so the collision is only true if my player is touching the triangle. (and the triangle is a png with transparent background)

**EDIT:** I found that i could use hitTestPoint instead of hitTestObject but how do i know what co ordinates to put into the parameters?

Comment: use a physic engine.

Answer (score 0):

I would abandon the use of hitTestObject() (or even hitTestPoint()) for collision detection. Instead, I'd use another algorithm for collision detection in your game

I'll assume your player is a (pretty) skinny box and you said that your obstacles are triangles. I'd first try using a basic method of checking if any of the triangle's points are within the player's bounding box. If it is, then you have a collision.

You could also go the other way and check if a player's points in the bounding box are within any triangle, but you may end up with an odd case where a triangle is poking in to the player, but none of the player's points are within the triangle (which can happen if a player gets a triangle right up between the legs >.> ). Also, by going triangle first, there are less points to check per player and triangle pair.

Note that using this simple method won't tell you how much intersection there is, but I'm guessing you may not need that, since you were using the hitTestObject() method before.

---

### Following my comment

I won't write the code for you line by line, but it's pretty easy to figure it out. So I'll describe one method:

Let's say your player is a rectangle that is 50px wide by 100px tall and the center of the player rectangle is set as the player's position. Half the width of the player is 25px and half the height is 50px.

So if the player is at say 240, 370 (a random spot I made up on screen), then to check if a point falls within you'd check if the x point is within 215 to 265 (240 +/- 25px) and if it is, then you'd check if the y point is within 320 and 420 (370 +/- 50px). If both these conditions are true, then the point is either touching or within the player box (so there is a collision). If any of them are false then the point is not (you could stop checking if the first condition is false, saving you a extra check operation).

Once you have that working (a point vs box test), then you'd just run a triangle's points through it to see if the triangle is intersecting the player box. How you get your triangle's points would vary based on your triangles.

Comment: ok thanks for your response but im pretty new to AS3 so how would i check if a triangle point is in the player's boundry box? (like an example code (:  )

Comment: ok but what functions will i have to use? (e.g hitTestObject or hitTestPoint or something.... Im new to Action Script... and in all honesty im only a month into flash

Comment: None - you don't have to use any. You would make your own function. What I've described is some math and if statements.